# Reading Excel File with openpyxl while populating form using Selenium takes too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, selenium, openpyxl

I'm filling out a web form which has input fields, dropdown menus, autocomplete fields and action buttons.

I'm pulling the data from an excel sheet using openpyxl. Initially it used to take between 3-4 seconds to populate these fields. After adding `read_only=True` to my readData function, it improved a bit but not as expected.

Does anyone has any suggestions on how I would be able to reduce the time it takes to populate each field? Any help is really appreciated. I'm leaving both the readData function as well as the populate_form which I use to fill out a text field as an example.

Cheers.

Method to read each cell:

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)

def readData(file, sheetName, row_num, column_num):
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
    return sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=column_num).value
```

---

Method to populate input field:

```
def fill_out_form(driver, path, input_sel, row_num, column_num):
    try:
        wait_for_element(driver, "//input[@id='" + input_sel + "']", 5)
        xls = readData(path, "Callcenter", row_num, column_num)
        input_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='" + input_sel + "']")
        input_el.click()
        if column_num == 9 or column_num == 40 or column_num == 67 or column_num == 121:
            xls = datetime.strftime(xls,'%d/%m/%Y')
        input_el.send_keys(xls)
        input_el.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        loading_el = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='sk-attr js-sk-attr sk-attr--labeled sk-attr--mandatory sk-attr--infonnized sk-attr--error sk-textbox clearfix']")))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(wait_not_spinning(loading_el))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Loading took too much time!-Try again")
```

Comment: If would surely increase your performance if you would load the workbook once and not every time when `readData` is called.

Comment: Rookie mistake from my side but after removing the loading piece of code from the function, I don't see a major increase in performance. I'll keep on searching for ways to improve the performance or maybe look into a difference library to pull the data from the xls and feed it to the web form. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your spreadsheet is huge I'm fairly certain the `wait_for_element` and `WebDriverWait` calls are taking the most time.
As was already suggested, try caching the spreadsheet(s) data using an efficient structure such as:

```py
dict[file][sheet] = list[row][column]
```

Since it seems you only have one file you can load the data using:

```py
def load_data(filename):
    data = {}
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True, read_only=True, keep_vba=False)
    for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
        data[sheet_name] = []
        sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
        for rows in sheet.iter_rows():
            row_elements = []
            for cell in rows:
                try:
                    value = cell.value
                except IndexError:
                    value = cell.internal_value
                row_elements.append(value)
            data[sheet_name].append(row_elements)
    return data
```

In order to use it, you would call `load_data(filename)` once (when your application starts) and access the loaded data later on using `xls_data` instead of `readData`:

```py
#application start
xls_data = load_data(filename)

....
# sheet_name->str, row_num->int, col_num->int
xls = xls_data[sheet_name][row_num][col_num]
```

The above will throw `KeyError` if the *sheet name* is invalid or `IndexError` for an invalid *row,column* combination.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that but I'll spend time on this as I really need to speed up the process since I have 5k records (excel rows) to input into that web form.

Comment: I did try it, thanks for that. Although I'm not sure how I would go about using it because the load data function you created only takes one argument (filename) and I would need to use it in my readData function which takes 4 arguments, see below:

readData(filename, "Callcenter", row_num, column_num)

Comment: I've added more details on how you can use the `load_data` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works great. Although it is still a bit slow (I'm working with a file with 500 rows) and each time I need to populate a field or a dropdown, I need to read from the excel sheet. I also need to write to that same xls so the read_only=True would prevent me from writing to the same file. I wonder if there is any other library similar to openpyxl which would allow me to read just the row I need, store that in memory (or create a temp file) and only read from that row throughout the script.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing the `readData` method using the 'xlrd' library.

It does not provide rich API like openpyxl but I'm sure it'll run faster.

Comment: Thanks for this, I would definately look into that library as I don't care much about the API but on the speed to read the data rather.

Answer (score 1):

When you fill in a web form, in the end the data will be sent to a server with a POST request.
What I would recommend is to use e.g. wireshark to *capture* that POST request.
Analyse that request to see what exactly is sent to the server. Then you can *create* such a POST request using the `requests` module.
That means you don't have to deal with selenium at all.

And as the others have mentioned, read the excel file only once.

Comment: I tried this already but I'm working on a corporate website with lots of restrictions and I'm not allowed to do any get/post requests. That's why I decided to do this with selenium. Thanks anyway for the suggestion, it's the best option to be fair as long as you have the right access.

Comment: So they're probably doing a lot of data validation in javascript, and they don't want you to do an end run around that? :-)

Comment: That's exactly it : ) I'll continue working on that POST request once I'm done with the selenium script first.